How to plot precision and recall value?
I am trying to visualize the graph about the precision-recall curve
This is the data frame provided:
import pandas as pd
import pyspark
import sklearn
from recommenders.utils.spark_utils import start_or_get_spark
from recommenders.evaluation.spark_evaluation import SparkRankingEvaluation, SparkRatingEvaluation

COL_USER = "UserId"
COL_ITEM = "MovieId"
COL_RATING = "Rating"
COL_PREDICTION = "Rating"

HEADER = {"col_user": COL_USER, "col_item": COL_ITEM, "col_rating": COL_RATING, "col_prediction": COL_PREDICTION,}

df_true = pd.DataFrame(
        {
            COL_USER: [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3],
            COL_ITEM: [1, 2, 3, 1, 4, 5, 6, 7, 2, 5, 6, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
            COL_RATING: [5, 4, 3, 5, 5, 3, 3, 1, 5, 5, 5, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 2, 1],
        }
    )
df_pred = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        COL_USER: [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3],
        COL_ITEM: [3, 10, 12, 10, 3, 5, 11, 13, 4, 10, 7, 13, 1, 3, 5, 2, 11, 14],
        COL_PREDICTION: [14, 13, 12, 14, 13, 12, 11, 10, 14, 13, 12, 11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5]
    }
)
spark = start_or_get_spark("EvaluationTesting", "local")

dfs_true = spark.createDataFrame(df_true)
dfs_pred = spark.createDataFrame(df_pred)

precisionatk = spark_rank_eval.precision_at_k()
recallatk = spark_rank_eval.recall_at_k()


I have tried several code but it not work well
PrecisionRecallDisplay.from_predictions(dfs_true, dfs_pred, ax=ax)

or
precision, recall, thresholds = precision_recall_curve(dfs_true, dfs_pred)
plt.fill_between(recall, precision)

This is the output I expect:
enter image description here
Source full code: https://github.com/recommenders-team/recommenders/blob/main/examples/03_evaluate/evaluation.ipynb

Sorry for bother. I'm fresher and I study and practice by myself. hope to receive everyone's help

Precision and recall are used for evaluating a binary classification problem. You can transform the original data so that:

True values are arranged as binary scores.
Prediction are scaled in a 0 to 1 range.

from sklearn.preprocessing import minmax_scale

y_true = df_true[COL_RATING].apply(lambda x: 1 if x > 3 else 0)
y_pred = minmax_scale(df_pred[COL_PREDICTION])

precision, recall, thresholds = precision_recall_curve(y_true, y_pred)

disp = PrecisionRecallDisplay(precision=precision, recall=recall)
disp.plot()
plt.show()


@RachelTran If the above answers your question, please accept it.

Calculating Precision and Recall only is not much useful. we should calculate F1 score which is harmonic mean of Precision and recall as F1 score is good representation of accuracy of classification model
here is some literature
https://www.v7labs.com/blog/f1-score-guide
using sckit-learn, u can calculate confusion matrix table which gives precision and recall
here is link to scikit learn to calculate confusion matrix
https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/plot_confusion_matrix.html#confusion-matrix
